# Style issue: font alignment with certain styling

Tags: bug, design, style, font

While doing some editing today, I've noticed the following issue with the style used on Ask Ubuntu:

[image]

This issue occurs when using either italic or bold italic text, ie: `***group***`. It is not evident in the preview but is noticeable once posted to the site. I cannot reproduce this issue on meta.

Browser: Chrome 31
OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: I don't see it on Wilf's example. Windows 7 , Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m

Comment: (I thought I had commented on this earlier, my bad) I'm fairly sure this is a font problem. The bundled webfont doesn't include the italic version (to save space) and that's why it's rendering awfully on a computer without the font. To test this you could install the Ubuntu font. I've retagged this so that Jin might see and fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in Firefox 27 on Ubuntu 13.10 *(also no noticeable problems on Fedora, Windows 7, mainly using Firefox + the ever hated Internet Explorer)* :

> On Meta AskUbuntu:
>   [image: text]
>   
> On Ask Ubuntu:
>   [image]

It should be fine, just a combination of Windows plus Chrome being daft.

You could also try downloading and installing the Ubuntu font from [here](http://font.ubuntu.com/)

---

using this *(with & without quoting formatting)*:

> user name, a new ***group*** is created with t
>
> strators?