# In the latest Google Chrome, KBD looks wrong

Tags: bug

I have just downloaded the latest stable chrome, from the official website, and installed it. I then restarted chrome.

Now to me <kbd>kbd</kbd> elements look like the old style like this:

[image]

It is not happening on other sites - is this how they have always looked here and I've never noticed?

Comment: IIRC the Meta style is different from the main site.

Comment: does the "kbd looks wrong." look different to the kbd above?

Comment: Not for me. I'm using Firefox. I don't remember if it looked different on meta before though. But as @oli said, it does look different on main.

Comment: @Dan, yeah, i'm quite confused...

Comment: It has been different on Meta for quite a while... that's why I did the other question, which if anything should be a duplicate of this one (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't say this is by design, but this is not a bug. It's just how the style is currently on Meta. Firefox is square and blocky too.

The main site is fine (even in Chrome). [Here's an example post](https://askubuntu.com/a/335771/449).